# Do fluorescent white materials exist?

Tags: fluorescence

From my understanding of fluorescence, a "fluorescent yellow material" (like in highlighters) is a material that contains yellow dyes and fluorescent dyes absorbing green to give yellow. Then, the material appears "more yellow" than usual objects because it has two sources of yellow.

---

If the above is right, it appears possible to create a "fluorescent white material" simply by having :

- three base colors (blue green red)
- three fluorescent dyes with their corresponding quantities to counter absorption from other dyes (2blue 2green 1red)

Does it exist ? Or am I making a mistake there ?

EDIT :

- The source is supposed to be sun light
- "white" is seen from the observer point of view, I don't mean all the visible spectrum, just 3 colors are enough.

Comment: This is a good, interesting question. No good answer yet. Give it some time though and if you don't get a definitive answer, try the chemistry stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

The phosphor on ordinary fluorescent tubes and also in white leds would seem to qualify; they take ultraviolet light and convert it to white(ish) light, using a blend of substances to get the color balance right.

Comment: Interesting ! +1 :) However I can't accept the answer since it doesn't take sun light as energy source.

Comment: The envelope of a fluorescent tube is UV-blocking for safety.   You can break the tube open to expose the phosphor to sunlight, though.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing you can be pretty sure of is, a surface cannot send out more light than is coming in, unless it has a heat source and is hot.  Fluorescent white surfaces would violate energy conservation, unless there was an ultraviolet source.  We do see that, it's called a "black light" and can make white clothing look fluorescent.

Comment: I'm not talking about emiting more light than what the material receives, just giving you this impression by taking energy from the UV (the source is supposed to be sun light).